# iTextSharp export asp net Panel

Tags: c#, asp.net, pdf, itext

I downloaded the last version of [iTextSharp](https://github.com/itext/itextsharp/releases) dll.

I use this for export in `PDF` this simple tag `Panel` in c#.

```
<asp:Panel ID="views" runat="server">
    <fieldset style="margin-left: 50px">
        <legend style="font-weight: bold; color: Red; margin-left: 10px;">Testing<br />
            <br />
            1. testing tble</legend>
        <br />
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <label for="Zone">
                        Zone<br />
                    </label>
                    <asp:Label ID="Zone" runat="server"></asp:Label></td>
                <td>
                    <label for="cp">
                        cp<br />
                    </label>
                    <asp:Label ID="cp" runat="server"></asp:Label></td>
                <td>
                    <label for="LinesName">
                        LinesName<br />
                    </label>
                    <asp:Label ID="LinesName" runat="server"></asp:Label></td>
                <td>
                    <label for="LinesCode">
                        LinesCode<br />
                    </label>
                    <asp:Label ID="LinesCode" runat="server"></asp:Label></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <label for="cl">
                        cl<br />
                    </label>
                    <asp:Label ID="cl" runat="server"></asp:Label></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </fieldset>
</asp:Panel>
```

And use this *code-behind* for populate the `Panel`:

```
    using (OdbcCommand command =
            new OdbcCommand(sql, cn))
    {
        try
        {
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("param1", Decrypt(Request.QueryString["id"].ToString()));
            command.Connection.Open();

            using (OdbcDataAdapter da = 
                new OdbcDataAdapter(command))
            {
                using (OdbcDataReader sdr = command.ExecuteReader())
                {
                    while (sdr.Read())
                    {
                        Zone.Text = sdr["Zone"].ToString();
                        cp.Text = sdr["cp"].ToString();
                        LinesName.Text = sdr["LinesName"].ToString();
                        LinesCode.Text = sdr["LinesCode"].ToString();
                        cl.Text = sdr["cl"].ToString();
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw ex;
        }
        finally
        {
            command.Connection.Close();
        }
```

And this code for export `PDF` :

```
private void PdfFiles1()
{
    Response.ContentType = "application/pdf";
    Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;filename=" + Decrypt(Request.QueryString["id"].ToString()) + ".pdf");
    Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache);
    StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
    HtmlTextWriter hw = new HtmlTextWriter(sw);
    views.RenderControl(hw);
    StringReader sr = new StringReader(sw.ToString());
    Document pdfDoc = new Document(PageSize.A4, 30f, 10f, 10f, 10f);
    HTMLWorker htmlparser = new HTMLWorker(pdfDoc);
    PdfWriter.GetInstance(pdfDoc, Response.OutputStream);
    pdfDoc.Open();
    htmlparser.Parse(sr);
    pdfDoc.Close();
    Response.Write(pdfDoc);
    Response.End();
}
```

I don't have error in `PDF` return but I have only first row of `table` :

```
<tr>
    <td>
        <label for="Zone">
            Zone<br />
        </label>
        <asp:Label ID="Zone" runat="server"></asp:Label></td>
    <td>
        <label for="cp">
            cp<br />
        </label>
        <asp:Label ID="cp" runat="server"></asp:Label></td>
    <td>
        <label for="LinesName">
            LinesName<br />
        </label>
        <asp:Label ID="LinesName" runat="server"></asp:Label></td>
    <td>
        <label for="LinesCode">
            LinesCode<br />
        </label>
        <asp:Label ID="LinesCode" runat="server"></asp:Label></td>
</tr>
```

The second row is not printed :

```
<tr>
    <td>
        <label for="cl">
            cl<br />
        </label>
        <asp:Label ID="cl" runat="server"></asp:Label></td>
</tr>
```

Please help me, thank you so much in advance.

Comment: Also, remove the line `Response.Write(pdfDoc);` because it doesn't do what you think it does.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your HTML table is unbalanced and iText is expecting every cell in the table to be accounted for. To fix it, just give your second row the proper number of cells:

```
<tr>
    <td colspan="4">
        <label for="cl">
            cl<br />
        </label>
        <asp:Label ID="cl" runat="server"></asp:Label></td>
</tr>
```

If you don't want to span them you just need to include empty cells:

```
<tr>
    <td>
        <label for="cl">
            cl<br />
        </label>
        <asp:Label ID="cl" runat="server"></asp:Label></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
</tr>
```

Or:

```
<tr>
    <td>
        <label for="cl">
            cl<br />
        </label>
        <asp:Label ID="cl" runat="server"></asp:Label></td>
    <td colspan="3"></td>
</tr>
```